# $\sum\cos=0$ and $\sum\sin=0$ when.......

Tags: trigonometry

help me to solve this problem. 
If $\cos(\beta-\gamma)+\cos(\gamma-\alpha)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)=-\frac{3}{2}$ then show that $\sum\cos=0$ and $\sum\sin=0$

Comment: What do you mean by sum(cos) and sum(sin)?

Comment: Perhaps it is $\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)+\cos(\gamma)$? Similarly for $\sin$?

Comment: yes Ian is right

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Expand the squares in
$$ (\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma)^2 + (\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma)^2 $$
and simplify using the usual trigonometric identities.